# Webpage with four color images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple webpage that contains 4 color images. When I hover over any of the images the original (xxxx1.jpg) is replaced by a black and white version (xxxxx2.jpg) of the same image, and then it reverts back to the original image after hover.

I'm declaring the same variable for both `handlerIn` and `handlerOut`:

```
var src = $(this).attr("src")
```

Can I declare the `var` just once somehow? I just can't seem to figure this out myself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "img" ).hover(
        function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("1.jpg", "2.jpg");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        }, 
        function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("2.jpg", "1.jpg");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Use CSS `background-image` to set the image on element, on `:hover` change the background image.

Comment: @Tushar I'll definitely do that for the practice, but this is an assignment for school that needs to be done entirely in jquery, there is no css for this page.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, this works. I'm literally on day 2 of jquery so I don't quite understand how this is working but I'll start picking it apart to figure it out:)

Comment: I've expanded a little on that comment in an answer (so have deleted the comment).

Comment: You can use the same approach, with jQuery `hover()` and CSS classes and `toggleClass` in callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do to make the code shorter is to take advantage of the fact that many jQuery methods like `.attr()` [accept a function as the second argument](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function), allowing you to replace this:

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("1.jpg", "2.jpg");
$(this).attr("src", src);
```

...with this:

```
$(this).attr("src", function(i, v) { return v.replace("1.jpg", "2.jpg"); });
```

(and similar in the other function.) What this does is call the function in the second argument with the current value of the attribute as the `v` argument, so you don't need a separate call to `.attr()` to find out what the current value is, and you don't need the `src` variable.

Then I'd change the `.hover()` code to [pass a single function to run on mouseenter and mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2), and use the `event` object to check whether it is mouseenter or mouseleave:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).attr("src", function(i, v) {
      return v.replace(/[12]\.jpg/, (e.type === "mouseenter" ? "2" : "1") + ".jpg");
    });
  });
});
```

This uses a regular expression `/[12]\.jpg/` with `.replace()` to find a string ending with `"1.jpg"` *or* `"2.jpg"`, and replace it with a value depending on the `event.type`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g5ncjjxo/

Comment: @Tushar - I didn't mention CSS in my answer because of the comments above about having to do it without CSS. But how would you use CSS classes to change images with different sources?

Comment: Fair Enough. Using CSS, instead of using `<img />` use other element and add class to it. The CSS Class will have `background-image: 1.jpg` and some other positioning styles. Another class will have `background-image: 2.jpg` which can be used to change the background image. In `hover()` callbacks `$(this).toggleClass('originalImage hoverImage')`

Comment: @Tushar - I meant, how would you apply that to multiple different elements in the page, each of which has its own pair of images, without having to create classes for each element?